# Zenoss - rename device from terminal

Tags: zenoss

I have aproximately 100 switches that need to be renamed in zenoss and a csv file with the IP address and corresponding name.
Is there a way to rename a device from the terminal so that I can knock up a quick script to parse the csv and rename the devices based on the IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is.  There is a `zendmd` CLI interface which provides a pythonic way to interact with Zenoss.

```
$ /usr/local/zenoss/zenoss/bin/zendmd
```

I'm not 100% sure, but "renaming" devices is probably akin to "moving" them in the devices hierarchy.  There are logs of examples [here](http://community.zenoss.org/community/documentation/wiki/zendmd) to get you started.

Comment: Recommend you hit #zenoss on  irc.freenode.net someone there likely knows exactly how to do this off the top of there head.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this while looking for the same solution. I took lukecyca's advice and asked on #zenoss.

The answer is to use zendmd to execute some python, either interactively or write a script to do it.

The following script was suggested by "frooderino" on #zenoos:

```
#file.csv is just a txt file with oldname,newname on each line
f = open('file.csv').read().split('\n')
print('starting rename')
for i in f:
  sync()
  o = i.split(',')
  d = dmd.Devices.findDevice(o[0])
  print('Current Name: %s' % d.id)
  d.renameDevice(o[1])
  commit()
  print('New Name: %s' % d.id)
print('done renames')
```

The input file would look like:

```
oldname1,newname1
oldname2,newname2
etc.
```

I adapted it slightly to run from a variable rather than a file but it worked just great.

you can run it in the zendmd shell using: `execfile("script.py")` at the `>>>` prompt. Alternatively, type it into the shell directly (remember to indent).